# Данные из одного списка в другой

Tags: java, list, коллекции, arraylist

У меня есть список 
`Arraylist list(с данными)` и

```
Arraylist list2 (пустой). Увидел как в статье используется метод `addAll()`
```

и захотел повторить и проверить пример в Idea:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Igor");
        list.add("Sasha");
        list.add("Evlampiy");

        list.addAll(list2);
        System.out.println(list2); // Не получилось так же 0 элементов
        list2.addAll(list);
        System.out.println(list2); // Получилось 
    }
}
```

Вставляет все элементы в указанной коллекции в этот список в указанной позиции (необязательная операция). Информация из документации.

 Я думал так будет работать: `list.addAll(list2)`
 Ну если описать своими словами: добавь данные из листа1`(list)` в лист2 `(list2)`, а оказалось наоборот. Подскажите! Может я неправильно делаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элементы добавляются в тот список, чей `addAll` вызывается, из того списка, который передается в этот метод. Что соответствует методу `add`, добавляющему элемент в список, чей метод вызывается. Чтобы работало так, как Вы ожидали, метод должен был бы называться `addTo`.

Comment: addTo() метода у list в моём случае нет метода addTo

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Я имел в виду, что он БЫ так назывался.

Comment: А как мне теперь из одного списка в другой перекинуть данные?

Comment: list2.addAll(list); ??? Вот так?

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Да, конечно.

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @ПетровченкоИван Пожалуйста. Успехов!

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89046/discussion-between---and-igor).

Answer (score 1):

```
list.addAll(list2);//данная операция добавляет элементы из list2 в list. т.к. list2 пустой, то и вывод в консоль пустой.
```